# Where can I find a mirror for full GNOME 3.14 & 3.26?

Tags: gnome3, source

I have been trying to find the source code for GNOME desktop versions 3.14 and 3.26, but it seems like there is nowhere to look anymore.

Are there any FTP's or mirrors with those? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gnome's sources are hosted by `gnome.org`.

More specifically:
https://download.gnome.org/sources/gnome-shell

As I'm on Debian-based system, I would probably just get a copy of the sources using `apt source gnome-shell`.  That would contain all of the distro-specific building rules and patches.

If you want the upstream releases and are [search-engine averse](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=gnome+sources), inspect the `/usr/share/doc/gnome-shell/copyright`.  All Debian-based source code will have a copyright file there.

On Debian-based systems, `gnome` is a metapackage which includes a ton of software (`gnome-maps`, `gnome-music`, `gnome-calendar`, `gnome-shell`).  I've assumed you're talking about `gnome-shell`, but you can browse sources of [their other projects](https://download.gnome.org/sources) too.

In case you are looking for their scm repositories you can find them at:

https://gitlab.gnome.org